# Domain in which every ideal is generated by at most three elements

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Does anyone know of a domain in which

1. every ideal is generated by at most three elements
2. at least one ideal is generated by no less than three elements?

What if three is replaced by n: a positive integer bigger than 3?

Comment: What about the subring $k[x^3,x^4,x^5]$ of $k[x]$? (I'm not sure whether it satisfies 1. If so, generalization for higher $n$ should work fine.)

Comment: @YCor It feels like it should work. But I think $k[[x^3,x^4,x^5]]$ definitely does.

Comment: @JeremyRickard thanks, of course you're right, localizing clears up all the mess.

Answer (score 9):

This is too long to be a comment.

If we restrict our attention to the case of *finitely generated* ideals, then there are two classical results by Heitmann and Swan.

> **Theorem 1 (Heitmann 1976)** A finitely generated ideal in a Prüfer domain of Krull dimension $n$ needs at most $n + 1$ generators.
>
> **Theorem 2 (Swan 1984)** For every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists a Prüfer domain of Krull dimension $n$ with an ideal $I$ that cannot be generated by less than $n+1$ elements.

Unfortunately, we cannot hope to use the above results in order to give an answer to the original question, since a Noetherian Prüfer domain is a Dedekind domain, and it is well-known that in such a domain every ideal is either principal or generated by two elements, see [MSE question 597543](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/597543/in-a-dedekind-domain-every-ideal-is-either-principal-or-generated-by-two-element).

**References.**

R. C. Heitmann: [Generating ideals in Prüfer domains](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1102867867), *Pacific J. Math.*, Volume **62**, Number 1 (1976), 117-126.

R. G. Swan: [$n$-generator ideals in Prüfer domains](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1102710580), *Pacific J. Math.*, Volume **111**, Number 2 (1984), 433-446.